# Separate DataFrame into parts based on column prefix and perform arithmetic on the parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table in which there are over 200 columns. The columns come with different pairs (e.g., two types of Benz), below is an example. What I want to do is to calculate the difference of each pair for a new column (like the last column as an example). I was thinking to separate the tables with two tables (A & B) according to the first letter, and sort the column. But is there a more efficient way in Pandas? Thanks!

```
A_Benz  B_Benz  A_Audi  B_Audi  A_Honda B_Honda dif_Audi
1   0   1   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   -1
1   0   0   1   0   0   -1
1   0   1   1   1   1   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   -1
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question after it has been answered. I have rolled back. Make sure next time your question is complete. Or do some research, then ask a separate question. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is your starting point -

```
df
   A_Benz  B_Benz  A_Audi  B_Audi  A_Honda  B_Honda
1       1       0       1       1        0        0
2       1       0       0       1        0        0
3       1       0       0       1        0        0
4       1       0       1       1        1        1
5       1       0       0       1        0        0
```

**Option 1**
This would make a nice use case for `filter`:

```
i = df.filter(regex='^A_*')
j = df.filter(regex='^B_*')

i.columns = i.columns.str.split('_', 1).str[-1]
j.columns = j.columns.str.split('_', 1).str[-1]

(i - j).add_prefix('diff_')

   diff_Benz  diff_Audi  diff_Honda
1          1          0           0
2          1         -1           0
3          1         -1           0
4          1          0           0
5          1         -1           0
```

If you want to add this back to the original dataframe, you'd use `concat`

```
df = pd.concat([df, (i - j).add_prefix('diff_')], axis=1)
```

---

**Option 2**
An alternative using `diff`; this does a lot of unnecessary subtraction:

```
import re

# if needed, order the columns correctly
df = df[sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: x.split('_', 1)[1])]
# compute consecutive column differences
df.diff(-1, axis=1).iloc[:, ::2].rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub('A_', 'diff_', x))

   diff_Benz  diff_Audi  diff_Honda
1        1.0        0.0         0.0
2        1.0       -1.0         0.0
3        1.0       -1.0         0.0
4        1.0        0.0         0.0
5        1.0       -1.0         0.0
```

A more performant version of this would be (similar to @jpp's method) -

```
c = sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: x.split('_', 1)[1])
df = df[c]

pd.DataFrame(
    df.iloc[:, ::2].values - df.iloc[:, 1::2].values, columns=c[::2]
)

   A_Audi  A_Benz  A_Honda
0       0       1        0
1      -1       1        0
2      -1       1        0
3       0       1        0
4      -1       1        0
```

Comment: Thanks! But may I ask what if the column name has more than one "_", like "A_Honda_typeS"?

Comment: @AlexXu I thought about that from the start, so I made sure that the code splits only once, on the first split. Take a look at the second parameter to `str.split`.

Comment: @AlexXu Also note that the second method does not have that issue, as long as the columns are sorted in the right order

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
s=pd.Series(df.columns).str.split('_',expand=True)[1]
df.groupby(s.values,axis=1).diff().dropna(axis=1)
Out[1252]: 
   B_Benz  B_Audi  B_Honda
1    -1.0     0.0      0.0
2    -1.0     1.0      0.0
3    -1.0     1.0      0.0
4    -1.0     0.0      0.0
5    -1.0     1.0      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. In the case what I am dealing with, the name actually comes with the underline "_", say "A_Honda_typeS, B_Honda_typeS". How to just split the string with the first "_"?

Comment: B_Honda_typeS  So you want it become Honda or Honda_typeS?@AlexXu

Comment: Sorry, didn't make it clear. I want the column name to be split at the first underscore (to differentiate A and B). In some cases, the names come with one or more underscores like Honda_typeS.

Comment: @AlexXu try with this line `s=pd.Series(df.columns).str.replace('_','~',1).str.split('~',expand=True)[1]`

Comment: Not sure why it's not working on my side. All I got is just the row index without any data. thanks anyway!

Comment: @AlexXu no sure what happen , it work fine on my side

Answer (score 1):

This is a `numpy`-based solution.

While performance may not be an issue, this should be more efficient than pandonic methods.

```
df = df[sorted(df, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[::-1])]

A = df.values
cars = [x[2:] for x in df.columns[::2]]

res = df.join(pd.DataFrame(A[:, ::2] - A[:, 1::2], columns=cars).add_prefix('Diff_'))
```

**Result**

```
   A_Audi  B_Audi  A_Benz  B_Benz  A_Honda  B_Honda  Diff_Audi  Diff_Benz  \
0       1       1       1       0        0        0          0          1   
1       0       1       1       0        0        0         -1          1   
2       0       1       1       0        0        0         -1          1   
3       1       1       1       0        1        1          0          1   
4       0       1       1       0        0        0         -1          1   

   Diff_Honda  
0           0  
1           0  
2           0  
3           0  
4           0
```

**Explanation**

- Sort your columns by car make, then prefix.
- Extract car makes via a list comprehension.
- Use `numpy` array slicing to build a difference dataframe and join this onto the original.